# How to map list of elements using java

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to java I  want to  map my for each loop  list elements  using map and get the value from map, but I am not able to use map in my for each statement. For your reference I post my code

```
private Item getItemManufacturerPriceCodes(Item item) {
          List<ItemPriceCode> itemPriceCodes = item.getItemPriceCodes;
       
          for(ItemPriceCode ipc : itemPriceCodes) {
              Optional<ManufacturerPriceCodes> mpc = manufacturerPriceCodesRepository.findByManufacturerIDAndPriceCodeAndRecordDeleted(item.getManufacturerID(), ipc.getPriceCode(), NOT_DELETED);
              if(mpc.isPresent())
                  ipc.setManufacturerPriceCode(mpc.get().getName());
          }
          item.getItemPriceCodes()
          .removeIf(ipc -> DELETED.equals(ipc.getRecordDeleted()));
          return item;
      }
```

I want to use my query code line above for each loop and pass list of price code inside map then get the values from map. this above  code works fine . when I pass one price code value the loop move one time but when pass ten value in that case loop move ten times. But I want loop always move one time  how many value I pass  using map. how can I do it.

I want to use below line above for each loop

```
   Optional<ManufacturerPriceCodes> mpc = manufacturerPriceCodesRepository.findByManufacturerIDAndPriceCodeAndRecordDeleted(item.getManufacturerID(), ipc.getPriceCode(), NOT_DELETED);
```

Getting same result using map. First of pass list of elements price code inside map and get the values from map then set those values.

I tried below way but it not working as above programme

```
private Item getItemManufacturerPriceCodes(Item item) {
          List<ItemPriceCode> itemPriceCodes = item.getItemPriceCodes();
        Optional<ManufacturerPriceCodes> mpc = manufacturerPriceCodesRepository.findByManufacturerIDAndPriceCodeAndRecordDeleted(item.getManufacturerID(), itemPriceCodes, NOT_DELETED);
          for(ItemPriceCode ipc : itemPriceCodes) {       
              if(mpc.isPresent())
                  ipc.setManufacturerPriceCode(mpc.get().getName());
          }
          item.getItemPriceCodes()
          .removeIf(ipc -> DELETED.equals(ipc.getRecordDeleted()));
          return item;
      }
```

> How can I map these list of price code and set them. My main aim is
> modify those piece of code using map and work same as  my above code
> that i explain in my problem statement.
> Is it possible to modify those codes using map.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Specifically what you are after in statement "when I pass one price code value the loop move one time but when pass ten value in that case loop move ten times. But I want loop always move one time how many value I pass using map". Is this a performance optimization?  Are you trying to avoid having to iterate over the itemPriceCodes and issue a separate query for each? If so, we would need more info on the findByManufacturerIDAndPriceCodeAndRecordDeleted method and the ManufacturerPriceCodes model, but it should be possible to pass in a list of itemPriceCodes

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to find a way to call setManufacturerPriceCode on a list of itemPriceCodes based on the ManufacturerPriceCodes that references them. Assuming there is no reference from the ItemPriceCode to the ManufacturerPriceCodes, I'd go about this differently:

In your ManufacturerPriceCodesRepository repository:

```
@Query("Select ipc.id, mpc.name from ManufacturerPriceCodes mpc join mpc.priceCode ipc where mpc.id = :id and ipc in :itemPriceCodes and mpc.recordDeleted = :notDeleted")
 List<Object[]> findMFPNameByIdAndRecordDeletedAndPriceCodes(String Id, <type> recordDeleted, List<ItemPriceCode> itemPriceCodes)
```

This will return a List<Object[]>, which each Object[] representing one ItemPriceCode id/name pair. You can use this in your getItemManufacturerPriceCodes method:

```
private Item getItemManufacturerPriceCodes(Item item) {
  List<ItemPriceCode> itemPriceCodes = item.getItemPriceCodes();
  List<Object[]> keyPairs= manufacturerPriceCodesRepository.findMFPNameByIdAndRecordDeletedAndPriceCodes(item.getManufacturerID(), NOT_DELETED, itemPriceCodes);

  Map<String,String> ipcToMFPNameMap = keyPairs.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(x -> x[0], x->x[1]));

  itemPriceCodes
          .forEach(ipc ->{ 
              if (ipcToMFPNameMap.get(ipc.getId())!=null)
                ipc.setManufacturerPriceCode(ipcToMFPNameMap.get(ipc.getId());
          })
          .removeIf(ipc -> DELETED.equals(ipc.getRecordDeleted()));
  return item;
}
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways than dealing with object[] with Spring, and certainly for the stream handling, but this is a general idea.